# Seiyria Bootstrap slider bar labels are not showing correctly in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using Seiyria Bootstrap slider bar as shown below. The problem is that when I click on the button to open the Bootstrap modal the slider labels are stacked on top of each other on the left as shown in the print screen. However, if I left or right click anywhere on the modal it shows it properly. In addition, I tried to use the example code outside the modal and it worked fine. I have got this example (Example 19) from this [website.](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) Bootstrap `Version 3.3.7`.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <span id="ex18-label-1" class="hidden">Example slider label</span>
          <input id="ex19" type="text" data-provide="slider" data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]" data-slider-ticks-labels='["short", "medium", "long"]' data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="3" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3" data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onClick="$('#exampleModalLong').modal();">click</button>
```

The slider version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.0/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
```

This is how the slider is shown when I click on the button to open the modal.

[image]

Expected Result - Also, When I click it is shown like this.

[image]

I have tried to inspect and fix the labels without any success. I would appropriate it if someone could tell me what I could possibly be doing wrong.

Comment: There are issues in the repo (see [#396](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/396), for instance) about this, as well as possible fixes. It would also be helpful to note which version of Bootstrap you are using.

Comment: Thank you. I have looked at the repo. Added the version of Bootstrap I am using.

Comment: That's the version of the slider. What version of Bootstrap itself are you using?

Comment: Ohh sorry, I am using Bootstrap `version 3.3.7`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `data-slider-ticks-positions`. Add that and it works properly.

```
<input id="ex19" 
       type="text"
       data-provide="slider"
       data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
       data-slider-ticks-labels='["short", "medium", "long"]'
       data-slider-ticks-positions="[0,50,100]"
       data-slider-min="1"
       data-slider-max="3"
       data-slider-step="1"
       data-slider-value="3"
       data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However, when I click to change the position of the slider the labels moves little bit. Is there any way through which you can make the labels stay at fixed position?

Comment: Thank you. This was annoying me.

For anyone using it as a React component the variable you need to set is. "ticks_positions"